# Writing the same thing to a text file multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I would like to write the input to a text file 25 times, so 25 lines of the same thing, what do I need to add to this code to achieve this.

```
tutorgroup = (input("Enter your tutor group name: "))      
filename = ("Tutor group");
with open (filename, "a") as f:
    f.write (tutorgroup + "\n")
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve the issue?

Comment: I have thought to use a loop, but I thought there may be a quicker way like , 25 or x 25, but I didn't know where in my code this would go or if it would even work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use string multiplication :

```
f.write((tutorgroup + "\n")*25)
```

And you better add an extension to the file, such as 'Tutor group.txt' (to avoid confusion with other files).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop.

From [Python Loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm):

> A loop statement allows us to execute a statement or group of
>   statements multiple times.

E.g.:

```
for i in range(25):
    f.write(...)
```